Powerbi Cross tab visual
I have following table structure. 



Person
Crime Type
WEEKID




P1
ASSAULT
WEEK-1


P1
BURGERLY
WEEK-3


P1
ROBBERY
WEEK-5


P1
VANDALISM
WEEK-3


P2
BURGERLY
WEEK-1


P2
ROBBERY
WEEK-2


P3
THEFT
WEEK-3


P3
VANDALISM
WEEK-3


P4
ASSAULT
WEEK-1


P4
VANDALISM
WEEK-1



I want to create cross tab where following structure ocmes. I want to identify how many person has done assult are involved in other crime and vice versa




ASSAULT
BURGERLY
ROBBERY
THEFT
VANDALISM




ASSAULT
2
1
1

2


BURGERLY
1
2
1

1


ROBBERY
1
1
2

1


THEFT



1
1


VANDALISM
2


1
3



